# Problem with calling dll file using LibraryLink with ParallelMap and Map for large data

Tags: librarylink

I am trying to call a .dll file via LibraryFunctionLoad where the .dll file is placed in "C:\ProgramData\Mathematica\SystemFiles\LibraryResources\Windows-\
x86-64\CoolProp.dll".

When I call this library for an individual or a small number of calls, it works.
I tried with Map, ParallelMap, multiple kernels (LaunchKernels[8]), Table, ParallelTable.

I got the following messages for both cases for mapping 5000 data.

I got several forms of "-- Message text not found -- ($Failed)".

I attached the screenshot of some of them.

I have tried 2 ways with the LibraryFucntionLoad (1) in the module of the function and (2) using SetSharedFunction.

I tried FindRoot, NMinimize, FindMinimum for searching the root. All cases work perfectly fine for data less than 1000 points. But I got the same type of error for points larger than 2000.

Here are my latest codes. I don't know how to upload .dll file here

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
Needs["Utilities`CleanSlate`"];
CleanSlate[];

CloseKernels[]
LaunchKernels[8];
$KernelCount


PropsSI =LibraryFunctionLoad["CoolProp", "PropsSI", {"UTF8String", "UTF8String", Real, "UTF8String", Real, "UTF8String"}, Real];
SetSharedFunction[PropsSI];

(* Mass fraction to mole fraction *)
mOlFracFromMassfracMixRefprop[pHi_?ListQ, rEf_?ListQ] := Module[{p = 101325., rEfRefP, mMassMix, y},
(* Check whether the mass fraction and the refrigerants have the same length *)
If[(Length@pHi == Length@rEf && Total@pHi == 1),
rEfRefP = ({StringJoin["REFPROP::", #]} // StringJoin) & /@ rEf;

mMassMix = 1/Total[pHi/(PropsSI["M", "P", p, "Q", 1, #] & /@ rEfRefP)];
y = mMassMix*pHi/(PropsSI["M", "P", p, "Q", 1, #] & /@ rEfRefP)

,

Print["Size or Fraction Error"]
]
];
SetSharedFunction[mOlFracFromMassfracMixRefprop];

(* Initial guessed pressure values *)
gUessGenRefprop[tEmp_?NumericQ, pHi_?ListQ, rEf_?ListQ ] := 
Module[{(* PropsSI, *)y, rEfMixRefP, pGues},

If[(Length@pHi == Length@rEf && Total@pHi == 1),

y = mOlFracFromMassfracMixRefprop[pHi, rEf]; (* 
mOlFracFromMassfracMixRefprop adds REFPROP:: string *)

rEfMixRefP = {StringJoin["REFPROP::", rEf // First // ToString, 
    "[", y // First // ToString, "]&"], 
   StringJoin[#1 // ToString, "[", #2 // ToString, 
      "]&"] & @@@ ((Take[#, {2, (pHi // Length) - 1}] & /@ {rEf, 
         y}) // Transpose), 
   StringJoin[rEf // Last // ToString, "[", y // Last // ToString,
     "]"]} // StringJoin;

pGues = PropsSI["P", "T", tEmp, "Q", 0, rEfMixRefP]

,

Print["Size or Fraction Error"]
]

];
SetSharedFunction[gUessGenRefprop];

(* Function to calculate the Bubble & Dew point temperature using the Pressure *)
tBubDewMixPhiRefprop[pRs_?NumericQ, pHi_?ListQ, rEf_?ListQ] := 
Module[{rEfMixRefP, y, tBubDew},


If[(Length@pHi == Length@rEf && Total@pHi == 1),

y = mOlFracFromMassfracMixRefprop[pHi, rEf]; (* 
mOlFracFromMassfracMixRefprop adds REFPROP:: string *)

rEfMixRefP = {StringJoin["REFPROP::", rEf // First // ToString, 
    "[", y // First // ToString, "]&"], 
   StringJoin[#1 // ToString, "[", #2 // ToString, 
      "]&"] & @@@ ((Take[#, {2, (pHi // Length) - 1}] & /@ {rEf, 
         y}) // Transpose), 
   StringJoin[rEf // Last // ToString, "[", y // Last // ToString,
     "]"]} // StringJoin;


tBubDew = {PropsSI["T", "P", pRs, "Q", 0, rEfMixRefP], 
  PropsSI["T", "P", pRs, "Q", 1, rEfMixRefP]}
,
Print["Size or Fraction Error"]
]
];
SetSharedFunction[tBubDewMixPhiRefprop];

(* Objective function for using Mathematica function *)
oBjFuncTbulkRefprop[pBulk_?NumericQ, tTarget_?NumericQ, pHi_?ListQ, 
rEf_?ListQ] := Module[{oBjFunc},

oBjFunc = (tTarget - Mean[tBubDewMixPhiRefprop[pBulk, pHi, rEf]])(* 
tBubDewMixPhiRefprop adds REFPROP:: string as necessary *)
];
SetSharedFunction[oBjFuncTbulkRefprop];


(* Local minimum using guessed pressured as an input *)
ClearAll[lOcalMinPguessRefprop];
lOcalMinPguessRefprop[{pStart_?NumericQ, tTarget_?NumericQ, 
pHi_?ListQ, rEf_?ListQ}] := 
Module[{$PerformanceGoal = "Speed", y, rEfMixRefP, rEfRefP, pMin, 
pMax, xIni, pCal},

pCal = 
a /. FindRoot[
   oBjFuncTbulkRefprop[a, tTarget, pHi, rEf], {a, pStart}] // Quiet

];
SetSharedFunction[lOcalMinPguessRefprop];

(* Generation of mass fraction input *)
mFrTernyR32Yf744 = 
Select[Tuples[{Range[0, 1, 0.01], Range[0, 1, 0.01], 
 Range[0, 1, 0.01]}], Total[#] == 1 &];

nLoopTernyR32Yf744 = mFrTernyR32Yf744 // Length

(* Input parameters for the calculation of ideal cycle analysis *)
iNputTernyR32Yf744 := {tEva -> 270.15, tCon -> 303.15, tSup -> 3., 
tSub -> 0., pHiRef -> {0.02, 0.23, 0.75}, 
rEfMixT -> {"CO2", "R32", "R1234yf"}}

(* Initial pressure for Evaporator *)
pIniEvapTernyR32Yf744 = 
Map[gUessGenRefprop[tEva /. iNputTernyR32Yf744, #, 
rEfMixT /. iNputTernyR32Yf744] &, mFrTernyR32Yf744]

(* Calculating the satuation pressure at the evaporator *)
pEvapTernyR32Yf744 = Table[(Pause[1]; 
pSatZeoMixPhiTempRefprop[pIniEvapTernyR32Yf744[[i]], 
tEva /. iNputTernyR32Yf744, mFrTernyR32Yf744[[i]], 
rEfMixT /. iNputTernyR32Yf744]), {i, 1, nLoopTernyR32Yf744}]


LibraryFunctionUnload[PropsSI]
```

[image]

[image]

I have been trying to sort it out almost two weeks already and still can't figure it out.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Show a *minimal* example please. Find the smallest piece of code that triggers the error and show that.  If you want to use a LibraryFunction with parallelization, then do not use `SetSharedFunction`. Load the LibraryFunction on each subkernel instead.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am now running the code to trigger the error. Meanwhile, can you tell me how to load libraryfunction on each subkarnel?

Comment: Look up `ParallelEvaluate`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I manage to execute parallel kernels.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is the exact problem with the previous codes. In this version, I have avoided repeated calling of the functions with StringJoin. The following code doesn't show the error message I got previously. Thanks to Szabolcs, I now use parallel execution which makes the program very fast.

The following is the functions.

```
pSatZeoMixRefprop[tTarget_?NumericQ, pHi_?ListQ, rEf_?ListQ] :=Module[{PropsSI =LibraryFunctionLoad["CoolProp", 
  "PropsSI", {"UTF8String", "UTF8String", Real, "UTF8String", 
   Real, "UTF8String"}, Real], rEfRefP, mMassMix, y, p = 101325., 
rEfMixRefP, rEfMixRef, pStart, pCal, pTdewBub},
(*Check whether the mass fraction and the refrigerants have the same length*)
If[(Length@pHi == Length@rEf && Total@pHi == 1),

rEfRefP = ({StringJoin["REFPROP::", #]} // StringJoin) & /@ rEf;
mMassMix = 
 1/Total[pHi/(PropsSI["M", "P", p, "Q", 1, #] & /@ rEfRefP)];
y = mMassMix*pHi/(PropsSI["M", "P", p, "Q", 1, #] & /@ rEfRefP);

rEfMixRefP = {StringJoin["REFPROP::", rEf // First // ToString, 
    "[", y // First // ToString, "]&"], 
   StringJoin[#1 // ToString, "[", #2 // ToString, 
      "]&"] & @@@ ((Take[#, {2, (pHi // Length) - 1}] & /@ {rEf, 
         y}) // Transpose), 
   StringJoin[rEf // Last // ToString, "[", y // Last // ToString,
     "]"]} // StringJoin;


pStart = PropsSI["P", "T", tTarget, "Q", 0, rEfMixRefP];

pCal = a /. (FindRoot[(tTarget - Mean[{
          PropsSI["T", "P", a, "Q", 0, rEfMixRefP], 
          PropsSI["T", "P", a, "Q", 1, rEfMixRefP]}])^2, {a, 
      pStart}] // Quiet);

pTdewBub = {pCal, PropsSI["T", "P", pCal, "Q", 0, rEfMixRefP], 
  PropsSI["T", "P", pCal, "Q", 1, rEfMixRefP]} 

,
Print["Size or Fraction Error"]
]
```

];

```
Parallelize@Map[pSatZeoMixRefprop[270.15, #, {"CO2", "R32", "R1234yf"}] &, Parallelize@Select[Tuples[{Range[0, 1, 0.1], Range[0, 1, 0.1], Range[0, 1, 0.1]}], Total[#] == 1 &]]
```

The above way solve the problem, but I don't know what caused the problem.

Thanks